# Comparison between Html with and without Html helpers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an asp.net mvc4 application in which some `Html.Helpers` are used in place of Html code

```
<form></form>
```

==>

```
@Html.BeginForm(){}
```

I used the concept of [Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx): the code becomes more readable and more maintainable and it's good. But I wonder :

1. if the model contains big data, did the binding of the model takes more time than a basic Html code?
2. Apart maintainability and readability, did the HTML Helpers have others benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This has nothing to do with html (helpers), binding is done by the framework when POST
2. 'Only' those benefits.

Comment: Did html helpers has some disadvantages? in which cases?

Comment: I'm using html helpers (default + my own) 99% of the cases. There are no real diasdvantages, just a matter of preference

Answer (score 1):

HTML Helpers are methods (extension methods) that basically write the HTML and some of them ensure the necessary attributes for the binding.

Writing the code yourself should be done when you want to write HTML in a different way than the helper.

Basically, even if you write your HTML code, you should enclose in methods things that can be repeated on multiple pages. As the performance goes, it's like writing a code in a C# method, or enclosing it into another method.

A default HTML helper does nothing more than writing your HTML after analyzing the parameters you send (you can also ensure binding by writing it by hand and have the right attributes).

If you are curious about BeginForm method, you can check the source code [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/FormExtensions.cs).